# Modify Reflection Color in EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, reflection

I'm currently working on a scene with screen space reflections (using light probes) in EEVEE. I would love to change the color of the reflection only (specifically to black&white but ideally with more room to modify it).

So for example, a red cube would appear black&white in a reflecting surface.
Is this possible? It seems like a pretty easy task but all my attempted solutions so far have failed.

- I tried using the light path node on the cube's shader but most attributes don't work in EEVEE (eg IsReflectionRay).
- I tried to convert the glossy shader of the mirror to RGB and set it's saturation to zero but it removes all the reflections altogether (it says this in the documentation too).

Could anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Is Reflection Ray"* works for Eevee (one of the few that works from *"Light Path"*).

[image]

If some other settings were to be checked:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!

It was actually just the reflection pane that I had setup incorrectly + I did not know i would be able to see a reflection of the cube without the lightprobe (which then gave me the IsReflectionRay of zero for both).
Also it did not help that the documentation does still label it as "Cycles only".